# How to parse gpx with unmarshal

Tags: go

I would like to parse a GPX file. I want to get the following information:

all Points (trkpt) in the file with their values for:

- longitude
- latitude
- elevation
- time

For this I wrote the structs:

```
type gpx file{
    filepointer *os.file
    points []xmlPoints
}

type gpx struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"gpx"`
    trks trk `xml:"trk"`
}

type trk struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"trk"`
    trksegs []trkseg `xml:"trkseg"`
}

type trkseg struct {
    XMLName xml.Name   `xml:"trkseg"`
    points  []XMLPoint `xml:"trkpt"`
}

type XMLPoint struct {
    XMLName   xml.Name  `xml:"trkpt"`
    longitude float64   `xml:"lon,attr"`
    latitude  float64   `xml:"lat,attr"`
    elevation float64   `xml:"ele"`
    time      time.Time `xml:"time"`
}
```

I used the following method to try and get these values:

```
func (f *GPXFile) setPoints() {
    //Reads the GPXfile to get a slice of all Points and set them to f.points
    //read GPXFile
    file, _ := os.Open(f.filePointer.Name())
    fileByte, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
    //get points
    var g gpx
    //should read points and puts them to &points, result empty
    err :=xml.Unmarshal(fileByte, &g)
    fmt.Print(err)
    //set points
    f.points = g.trks.trksegs[1].points
}
```

My GPX Files Look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx version="1.1" ...>
 <metadata>
  <time>2019-09-14T13:14:17.094Z</time>
 </metadata>

 <trk>
  <name>Cube – Sa., 14. Sep. 2019, 15:14</name>
  <trkseg>
  </trkseg>
  <trkseg>
   <trkpt lat="49.3547198000" lon="9.1508659200"><time>2019-09-14T13:14:00.000Z</time><extensions><gpxpx:PowerInWatts>120</gpxpx:PowerInWatts></extensions></trkpt>
   <trkpt lat="49.3546998700" lon="9.1509324100"><time>2019-09-14T13:14:10.003Z</time><extensions><gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension><gpxtpx:atemp>22.9</gpxtpx:atemp></gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension><gpxpx:PowerInWatts>120</gpxpx:PowerInWatts></extensions></trkpt>
   <trkpt lat="49.3547521100" lon="9.1510961900"><time>2019-09-14T13:14:14.293Z</time><extensions><gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension><gpxtpx:atemp>22.9</gpxtpx:atemp></gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension></extensions></trkpt>
   <trkpt lat="49.3547585400" lon="9.1513071400"><time>2019-09-14T13:14:20.310Z</time><extensions><gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension><gpxtpx:atemp>22.9</gpxtpx:atemp></gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension></extensions></trkpt>
   <trkpt lat="49.3549890600" lon="9.1519649400"><ele>172.50</ele><time>2019-09-14T13:14:30.276Z</time><extensions><gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension><gpxtpx:atemp>22.8</gpxtpx:atemp><gpxtpx:speed>5.54</gpxtpx:speed></gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension></extensions></trkpt>
   <trkpt lat="49.3550175500" lon="9.1520317100"><ele>172.23</ele><time>2019-09-14T13:14:32.291Z</time><extensions><gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension><gpxtpx:atemp>22.8</gpxtpx:atemp><gpxtpx:speed>4.86</gpxtpx:speed></gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension></extensions></trkpt>
   <trkpt lat="49.3550991300" lon="9.1520247100"><ele>171.90</ele><time>2019-09-14T13:14:34.290Z</time><extensions><gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension><gpxtpx:atemp>22.8</gpxtpx:atemp><gpxtpx:speed>4.54</gpxtpx:speed></gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension></extensions></trkpt>
   <trkpt lat="49.3551844700" lon="9.1519891400"><ele>171.33</ele><time>2019-09-14T13:14:36.275Z</time><extensions><gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension><gpxtpx:atemp>22.8</gpxtpx:atemp><gpxtpx:speed>4.88</gpxtpx:speed></gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension></extensions></trkpt>
   <trkpt lat="49.3553612700" lon="9.1518673700"><ele>170.61</ele><time>2019-09-14T13:14:40.015Z</time><extensions><gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension><gpxtpx:atemp>22.8</gpxtpx:atemp><gpxtpx:speed>5.55</gpxtpx:speed></gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension><gpxpx:PowerInWatts>121</gpxpx:PowerInWatts></extensions></trkpt>
  </trkseg>
 </trk>
</gpx>
```

The problem is, that from the unmarshal function I get a `gpx` with `trk` in it, but the `trkseq` is nil...
if I make `trkseq` in `trk` a single `trkseq` istead of an array, it works but the points are nil. So I want to know how I can parse a array of `trkseq`. From there I could use the same method to get the array of points.

Comment: Your struct field names are not exported. Capitalize them so unmarshal can set them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When marshalling/unmarshalling any type of encoded/serialised data in golang, the types into which you unmarshal are passed as an `interface{}` type at some point. The (un)marshalling code will have to rely on the `reflect` package to find tags and fields it can use to map data onto. The only fields this code can use (and write to) are exported fields (fields that start with a capital letter). Your types all have unexported fields and types (private, if you will).

Just change stuff like this:

```
type gpx struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"gpx"`
    trks    trk      `xml:"trk"`
}
```

To

```
type Gpx struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"gpx"`
    Trks    Trk      `xml:"trk"`
}
```

Also, in Golang the convention is to use all caps for acronyms (e.g. `URL`, not `url` or `Url`), so arguably, you'll want:

```
type GPX struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"gpx"`
    TRKS    TRK      `xml:"trk"`
}
```